# onmouseover for menu created with foor loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, menu, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have created one simple menu using for loop in javascript because the most elements are the same for every 'tab', so I did it all in one go using the for loop.

My question is how can I use onmouseover event to change the tab's background color when I hover on it using mouse.

Example:

```
TopValues = [ "130px", "163px", "196px" ];
MenuNames = [ "Home", "Articles", "Contact" ];
MenuItemLinks = [ "#", "#", "#" ];
MenuItemTitles = [ "Go To Home", "Go To Articles", "Go To Contact" ];

window.onload = function makeMenu() {
    for(var i=0; i<MenuNames.length; i++) {
        var menu = document.createElement('a');
        menu.text = MenuNames[i];
        menu.title = MenuItemTitles[i];
        menu.href = MenuItemLinks[i];
        document.body.appendChild(menu);

        menu.style.position = "fixed";
        menu.style.border = "1px solid red";
        menu.style.width = "90px";
        menu.style.top = TopValues[i];
        menu.style.left = "5px";
        menu.style.padding = "5px";
        menu.style.borderRadius = "5px";
        menu.style.textDecoration = "none";
        menu.style.background = "yellow";
        menu.style.color = "red";

    }
    menu.onmouseover = function() { menu.style.background = "orange"; };
    menu.onmouseout = function() { menu.style.background = "yellow"; };
}
```

In this example, only the last tab changes the background color as it should. Can you help me to understand how I'm supposed to do it.

I was thinking to make an empty array and assign to every tab it's id, and using another for loop and if statements to determine which tab is it, and change it's color, but I didn't manage.

Thanks everyone

Comment: Move the event handlers a tiny bit up, inside the loop. And use this inside the event handlers, not menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move event listener inside loop.

```
 for(var i=0; i<MenuNames.length; i++) {
        var menu = document.createElement('a');
        menu.text = MenuNames[i];
        menu.title = MenuItemTitles[i];
        menu.href = MenuItemLinks[i];
        document.body.appendChild(menu);

        menu.style.position = "fixed";
        menu.style.border = "1px solid red";
        menu.style.width = "90px";
        menu.style.top = TopValues[i];
        menu.style.left = "5px";
        menu.style.padding = "5px";
        menu.style.borderRadius = "5px";
        menu.style.textDecoration = "none";
        menu.style.background = "yellow";
        menu.style.color = "red";
        (function(el) {
            el.onmouseover = function() { el.style.background = "orange"; };
            el.onmouseout = function() { el.style.background = "yellow"; }
        }(menu));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my problem :)
Can you also just please explain me how did you managed to do that, I'm confused in what does that (menu) gets / returns, and why did you put the whole code inside ( ); on the end of the loop.

Thanks one more time